# Water percentage

Tags: earth-like, hard-science, water, habitability

All the worlds I've seen built by me or others have surfaces that are mainly water. Is it possible for a habitable world to exist if the world is mainly land? I'm only talking about 55-65 percent land. Other than that, it is exactly like Earth for all the reasons you need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2936) discussing life on exoplanets:

> Rocky planets within their star's habitable zones have the highest priority, as these have the potential to harbor life.

So, apparently the percentage of the surface which is water does not play into whether life can exist. The primary factor for having a potential of life is being within the habitable zone of their star.

Comment: True, but being in the habitable zone makes it more likely for water to exist - in fact, that's part of the requirements for the traditional habitable zone. It's a circular argument.

Comment: @HDE226868 Not quite. The primary factor is being in the habitable zone. It also should *have some water*, but the percentage of the surface that is covered is not a factor.

Comment: I think I understand. My argument was based on the idea that planets further in the habitable zone are more likely to have more water, but that's not necessarily true.

Comment: That...is FAR from the only priority in determining whether or not an exoplanet is habitable (particularly by advanced life)...but your answer to his question remains correct. See the following link for a write up on the 'musts' for microbial life to be viable. There is a much longer list for intelligent life. Of interest to the OP, it also includes details on 'Minimum Water Content' required for bacteria as we know it to function: http://www.pnas.org/content/111/35/12628.full.pdf

Comment: Technically, the percentage of water may matter significantly when at a particular low percentage range, especially if some reservoirs of water tend to evaporate or otherwise are short lived (on an astronomical timescale).

Comment: @major norwal check out this page: http://planetplanet.net/2014/05/20/building-the-ultimate-solar-system-part-2-choosing-the-right-planets/